# General Advice on Ubuntu

Tags: installation, uninstall, windows-8

I am interested in installing Ubuntu as an additional operating system, but I am not sure, yet. Before reaching a final decision, there are some things I need to know about Ubuntu:

1. Where can I download it?
2. As a Windows 8 user, are there any pages with instructions about the requirements and installation process?
3. After installing Ubuntu, will I have the ability to uninstall it and if yes, how?
4. Can the installing and uninstalling Ubuntu damage my computer?

Comment: To other users of Ask Ubuntu : please do not downvote questions unless you explain why in a comment, for education purposes.

Comment: 1. When you Google for the word "ubuntu" the very first result is the official site which has a link beneath it labeled "Download" that isn't hard to figure out/ 2.Same, check the Ubuntu site or search this site there's at least 1 question that addresses this./ 3. This has also been answered here, Search. / 4. That's pretty common sense, changing the OS won't light the computer on fire, at best is what the user ends up doing wrong.

Comment: Search Google & [Ubuntu Wiki](http://wiki.ubuntu.com). You don't need these quesions.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to be able to try Ubuntu out for a bit, maybe to get a feel and decide if it is right for you. I would suggest giving Wubi a go.

you can find information on wubi here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi

Wubi is a program that allows you to 'install' Ubuntu like any other Windows program. when it is finished, you can reboot the computer and and boot into either Windows or Ubuntu. the best part about Wubi, if you want you can uninstall it right through the normal "Windows Add/Remove Programs" control panel.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes. I recomend installing Wubi if you are new

Answer (score 0):

1. You can download Ubuntu 12.04 from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop Once you did your download, this page will lead you to another one explaining how to install Ubuntu.
2. Yes there are countless instructions on how to install Ubuntu. You can easily find a guide on the web. Here is a video on how to dual boot : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LokDqte3sA4
3. Yes you will depending if you are dual booting or using Wubi. Just delete the partition and once again countless guides on it here. Just search for it.
4. It shouldn't, but if it does you can do another reinstall and that should fix it.